# How to efficiently do cross-validation with big.matrix in R?

Tags: r, bigdata, cross-validation, r-bigmemory

I have a function, as follows, that takes a design matrix `X` with class type `big.matrix` as input and predicts the responses.

**NOTE:** the size of matrix `X` is over 10 GB. So I cannot load it into memory. I used `read.big.matrix()` to generate backing files `X.bin` and `X.desc`.

```
myfun <- function(X) {
## do something with X. class(X) == 'big.matrix'
}
```

My question is that, **how I can do cross validation efficiently with this huge big.matrix?**

**My attempt:** (It works, but is time consuming.)

- Step 1: **for each fold**, get indices for training `idx.train` and test `idx.test`;
- Step 2: divide `X` into `X.train` and `X.test`. Since `X.train` and `X.test` are also very large, I have to store them as `big.matrix`, and create associated backing files (`.bin`, `.desc`) for the training and test sets **for each fold**.
- Step 3: feed the `X.train` to build the model, and predict responses for `X.test`.

**The time-consuming part is Step 2**, where I have to create backing files for training and test (almost like copy/paste the original big matrix) many times. For example, suppose I do 10-fold cross validation.  Step 2 would take over 30 minutes for creating backing files for all 10 folds!

To solving this issue in Step 2, I think maybe I can divide the original matrix into 10 sub matrices (of class type `big.matrix`) just once. Then for each fold, I use one portion for testing, and **combine the remaining 9 portions as one big matrix for training**. But the new issue is, there is no way to combine small `big.matrix` into a larger one efficiently without copy/paste.

Of course I can do distributed computing for this cross validation procedure. But I am just wondering whether there is a better way to speed up the procedure if just using a single core.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that @cdeterman's answer doesn't work when `X` is very large. The reason is that the `mpermute()` function permutes the rows by essentially doing copy/paste. `mpermute()` calls `ReorderRNumericMatrix()` in C++, which then calls `reorder_matrix()` function. This function reorders the matrix by looping over all columns and rows and doing copy/paste. See the source code [here](https://github.com/fcastanedo/bigmemory-R/blob/fc4544fced19891df3d2a1aedad868739833b4ce/src/bigmemory.cpp#L843-L860).

Are there any better ideas for solving my problem?? Thanks.

**END UPDATE**

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use the `sub.big.matrix` function.  This avoids any further copies and points the same original data.  However, it can currently only subset contiguous rows.  So you will want to permute your rows first.

```
# Step 1 - generate random indices
idx <- sample(nrow(X), nrow(X))
mpermute(X, idx)

# Step 2 - create your folds
max <- nrow(bm)/10 # assuming 10 folds
idx_list <- split(seq(nrow(bm)), ceiling(seq(nrow(bm))/max))

# Step 3 - list of sub.big.matrix objects
sm_list <- lapply(idx_list, function(x) sub.big.matrix(bm, firstRow = x[1], lastRow = x[length(x)]))
```

You now have the original `big.matrix` split into 10 different matrices that you can use as you like.

Comment: Thanks @cdeterman. This is really good to know. However, this doesn't solve the issue completely. I still have to figure out how to combine the 9 sub big.matrix into one for training.

Comment: Alternatively, based on your suggestion, it seems that I can ``mpermute`` the matrix each time by putting the test portion (where idx == fold id) to the bottom and then can use ``sub.big.matrix`` to get training and test parts. But since ``mpermute`` CHANGES the original matrix, this seems not working as well.

Comment: The second approach seems work if I keep updating the index vector used in ``mpermute``. Thank you very much, @cdeterman.

Comment: Hi @cdeterman, it turns out that your approach doesn't work because ``mpermute()`` takes a long time. I am wondering whether you have other ideas for this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AaronZeng at this point this is still probably the best solution.  It may take a while but at least it will fit RAM for you and you can ultimately split the matrix up.  Non-contiguous subsetting just currently isn't supported.  Feel free to submit an issue [here](https://github.com/kaneplusplus/bigmemory/issues)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sample(nrow(bm), nrow(bm))` and `mpermute(bm, idx)` in the first lines?